# Replace named function with anonymous in javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I've seen EVERY example of how to replace anonymous functions with named ones.  I'm looking for how a named function can be changed to an anonymous one. I'm looking to just optimize my code slightly.  I understand how the anonymous function works, I just can't get the syntax right in this example. 
Additionally, the doWork function is a big beast. I need it to stay named.

NOTE: I did google, and I'm either searching the wrong terms, or not a lot of people want to know how to do this. I humbly beg for SO's forgiveness of my failure to find this answer somewhere else.

NOTE2: Please ignore my use of closure with this.formFields.  Just assume it won't change ever. I'm setting it at an earlier time.

My code:

```
function doWork(serviceResponse, theFormFields){
     // Process stuff like jQuery or console test stuff etc
}

// THIS NAMED FUNCTION IS WHAT I WANT TO BE ANONYMOUS
function createCallback(formfields) {
   return function(data) {
        // This reference to the 'formfields' parameter creates a closure on it.
        doWork(data, formfields);

    };
}

// THE ABOVE FUNCTION *COULD* be anonymously declared in the getJSON 
$.getJSON(jsonService + callString, createCallback(this.formFields));
```

Comment: Just write it inline like mentioned. Where you can mention a function name you can mention a function definition, it will work the same. Not sure if there are advantages thought, I guess that depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(
    jsonService + callString,           // your param #1
    (function (formField) {             // here we create and execute anon function
                                        // to put this.formFields into the scope as formField variable
                                        // and then return required callback
        return function (data) {
            doWork(data, formField);
        }
    })(this.formFields)
);
```

Comment: Although your answer is very similar to ihimv's answer, why do you include an additional parenthesis after you declare the anonymous, and he doesn't.  Is this just more strict?

Comment: This way I've made two things with single line of code: 1. defined a function `function (formField) { ... }` 2. immediately called with argument value `this.formFields`. And I called it with an argument which was copied into the scope of that function and since that I'm not afraid if something will change the value of `this.formFields`.

Comment: okay this answer and my answer both are wrong. So i have deleted my answer

Comment: Can you elaborate? The code seems to work. What is wrong? Also, I chose this answer because stas.yaranov went to the trouble to explain *why* everything is as it is.  I am trying to learn more.